# Get corresponding lines in LESS editor for VS2013?

Tags: less, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to get some sort of a highlight or other indicator to map the LESS class markup to the generated markup? There are many times where I need to debug a style in Chrome but need to take an extra step to look up the line in LESS in VS. Basically, I need to work backwards. Thanks.

Comment: This is what you're looking for: http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/12/28/debug-less-with-chrome-developer-tools/. You'll need to follow the instructions on how to enable source maps in chrome (this is done by typing in `chrome://flags/` and enabling experimental developer tools. I won't go on as the article is very informative and tells you all you need to know.

Comment: @adaam please could you rewrite your comment as an answer, so it can be accepted?